# Drop an Item for 10 Points on a Scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making this game, and in it there is a drill that mines 10 blocks down when you drop it. I want to add 10 points to the scoreboard when that happens, but my problem is that I don't know how to give that specific player that dropped it the points, so this is what I did:

First, I made the objective...

```
/scoreboard objectives add +10Drill stat.drop.minecraft.double_plant
```

Then, when you drop a sunflower, it adds 1 point.
So I need to know how to detect if a player gets that 1 point, and give 10 points in a different objective.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what kind of version you're playing on. But i found the solution for 1.13

/execute if entity @p[scores={+10Drill=1..}] run scoreboard players set @p ANOTHER_OBJ 10

Comment: Yes, I did think of that, but I'm in 1.11.2, so that is my problem,

Comment: But, now that I think about it, wouldn't...   /execute @p[score_+10Drill_min=1] scoreboard players set @p OtherObjective 10.     Work?